# how to make alias to lowercase in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

how to make alias to lowercase in mongodb

```
fname: { $arrayElemAt: ['$created_users.first_name', 0] },
```

How to convert the value to lowecase tried this way doesn't work for me please guide

```
fname: { $arrayElemAt: { $toLower: ['$created_users.first_name', 0] } },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this should work

```
fname: { $toLower: { $arrayElemAt: ['$created_users.first_name', 0] } },
```